# How to wait for go-routines to complete?

Tags: go, goroutine

Below is the scenario:

```
inputCh := g(abc) // return <- chan []string


slice := make([]map[string][]string, 0)
m := sync.Mutex{}
for whatever := range inputCh {
    go func(whatever []string) {
        matches := f(xyz, whatever) // returns map[string][]string
        m.Lock()
        slice = append(slice, matches)
        m.Unlock()
    }(whatever)
}

z := merge(slice...)
```

where we do no know, when `inputCh` gets closed(`close(inputCh)`)

We need to invoke `merge(slice...)` only after all go-routines gets completed and updated `slice`

---

Not sure, if `sync.WaitGroup` can be used.

How to ensure `merge(slice...)` gets invoked only after `slice` gets updated by all go-routines?

Comment: If I knew `len(inputCh)` then I would have launched only these many goroutines, isn't it?

Comment: @guenhter yes it does

Answer (score 1):

Use `sync.WaitGroup` and check when channel was closed

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

for {
    whatever, ok := <-inputCh
    if !ok { // check inputCh is close
        break
    }
    // add delta
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(whatever []string) {
        matches := f(xyz, whatever)
        m.Lock()
        slice = append(slice, matches)
        m.Unlock()
        // goroutine is done
        wg.Done()
    }(whatever)
}

// waits until all the goroutines call "wg.Done()"
wg.Wait()
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `sync.WaitGroup`.

```
// create a work group
var wg sync.WaitGroup
// add delta
wg.Add(len(inputCh))

slice := make([]map[string][]string, 0)
m := sync.Mutex{}
for whatever := range inputCh {
    go func(whatever []string) {
        matches := f(xyz, whatever) // returns map[string][]string
        m.Lock()
        slice = append(slice, matches)
        m.Unlock()
        // signal work group that the routine is done
        wg.Done()
    }(whatever)
}
// waits until all the go routines call wg.Done()
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: if channel is not closed and empty `len()` return `0` https://play.golang.org/p/xp1xRi5pVPP

Comment: If I knew `len(inputCh)` then I would have launched only these many goroutines, isn't it?